# Django:how to install Spatialite for django on windows 10

Tags: python, django, windows, spatialite

I am using the spatial database **spatialite** for a django project for the first time, I followed the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/), when I reach the step that says " run the configure script" I don't konow how to run that script, and witch script exactly, is it the **configure** file or **configure.ac**.

can you please help me, or is there an other way to intall Spatialite for a django project.
Thanks.

Comment: For Windows, the docs link to a site with binaries so that you don’t have to build from source.

Comment: so I have to download the libspatialite library? how can I install it for my project?